# update button property from another class and thread in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, properties

im new to C# language and i would appreciate any help/feedback on the following issue.

Basically, im trying to develop a program such that it has two classes class1(main thread) and class2. class1 has a button and class2 starts a thread and do some calculations. How can i update any property of the button in class1(main) from class2 within the thread in class2?

here is an example i would like to do

```
// CLASS 1 is a win form 
class1:form
{

public btn_click()
{
// call function startthread from class2
 btn.Enabled = false;
 startthread()
}

}
// CLASS 2 is not a winform
class2
{
 public startthread()
 {
  Thread worker = new Thread(doCalculation)
 }

 public doCalculation()
 {
  // do some calculation then
  // blahhh
  // blahhh
  // HERE I NEED SOMEHOW ENABLED MY BUTTON 
}
}
```

Comment: Your class has a button? Can you give a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a bit on the UI framework you're using.  As an example, say you wanted to update the text written on the button.

If you're using WPF, you could use:

```
class1Instance.TheButton.Dispatcher
      .BeginInvoke( (Action) () => class1Instance.TheButton.Content = "Foo" );
```

With Windows Forms, you'd use:

```
class1Instance.TheButton
      .BeginInvoke( (Action) () => class1Instance.TheButton.Text = "Foo" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to bring the modifying code back onto the the main thread, regardless whether its WPF or Winforms, cross-thread access to the UI is either explicitly disallowed (usually) or strongly discouraged and buggy.

There are a lot of ways to do this, in Winforms I typically use `Control.Invoke` like this:

```
public void UpdateMyTextBox(string NewText) 
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
       Invoke(new Action<string>(UpdateMyTextBox), NewText);
    else
       myTextBox.Text = NewText;
}
```

In this example, the `InvokeRequired` property will check to see if it's being called on the UI thread, and if not, we will call `Invoke` which will place the request onto the UI thread.

In WPF, you watch to use the `Dispatcher`, and you do so in a very similar way:

```
public void UpdateMyWpfTextBox(string NewText)
{
    if(!CheckAccess())
       Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<string>(UpdateMyWpfTextBox), NewText);
    else
       myTextBox.Text = NewText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure what your trying to do here, but this is best an answer I can come up with, considering the questions. I'm going to assume this is a winforms application

Class2 is going to need a reference to the button in Class 1. So you'll need to pass that to it.

Once Class2 has reference to the button you can attempt to modify the property as

```
btn.Text = "New Text";
```

I'm going to assume again that you've tried this route, got an exception and so you posted your question.  The reason you got the exception was that your btn and your class2 are running in separate threads.  To get around this, you can call invoke on the button.  I often handle this like this.

```
private void SetButtonText(string newText) {
    if (btn.InvokeRequired) {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => SetButtonText(newText)));
    }
    else {
        btn.Text = newText;
    }
}
```